# Anchor sysvar account mismatch

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I was using `Sysvar<'info, SlotHashes>` in my context. like this;

```
pub struct FullFillPlunderBet<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    pub plunder_box: Account<'info, PlunderBox>,
    #[account(seeds = [b"authority"],bump, has_one = owner)]
    pub house_authority: Account<'info, HouseAuthority>,
    #[account(mut, constraint = plunder_box.key() == plunder_bet.plunder_box,seeds = [b"plunder_bet",uuid.as_bytes(), user.as_ref()], bump)]
    pub plunder_bet: Account<'info, PlunderBet>,
    pub slot_hashes: Sysvar<'info, SlotHashes>,
}
```

And calling the rpc in my test script like this

```
let tx = await program.methods.fullfillPlunderBet(uuid, lootboxUser.publicKey, hash).accounts({
      houseAuthority,
      plunderBet,
      plunderBox: plunderBox.publicKey,
      owner: provider.publicKey,
      slotHashes: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_SLOT_HASHES_PUBKEY
    }).rpc()
```

But it gives an error

```
Error: AnchorError caused by account: slot_hashes. Error Code: AccountSysvarMismatch. Error Number: 3015. Error Message: The given public key does not match the required sysvar.
```

Comment: What version of anchor are you using?